# What is the correct choice (make -do) a surprise?

Tags: word-choice

If you want to surprise a person ,what will you say , I *made* a surprise or I *did* a surprise? I think *make* is the correct choice.

Comment: You can ***give** someone **a surprise***, but it's not a very common usage compared to plain ***surprising** someone*. And there aren't really any common English verbs that can be used in the construction ***He [verbed] a surprise***, where *[**to verb**]* carries the sense of "to create".

Comment: ...note that we can certainly say *He **caused surprise** among [the people he surprised]*, with no article. But [*He caused **a** surprise](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=caused+a+surprise+among%2Ccaused+surprise+among&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccaused%20a%20surprise%20among%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaused%20surprise%20among%3B%2Cc0) among [his audience]* (with the article) is very uncommon phrasing.

Comment: "prepared a surprise"

Answer (score 3):

Neither wording sounds natural.

As a noun, "surprise" fits in a category with things like "party", "event", and "accident". These are not actions that you carry out, so "do" doesn't fit; nor are they things that you create or craft, so "make" doesn't fit either. Instead, they are things that happen, even if you *intend* for them to happen.

You can "plan a surprise", and if someone or something surprises you, you can "have a surprise".

For a direct action, you generally have to mention the person who *receives* the surprise. In that case, you can either use "surprise" as a verb, rather than a noun:

> I surprised my friend

Or, you can use "give", with an indirect object:

> I gave my friend a surprise

Note that you can also use surprise as an *adjective*, in which case it might qualify a noun which *does* fit with "make", as in:

> I made a surprise birthday cake for my friend

Comment: Or 'I gave him/her a surprise'.

Comment: @KateBunting Ooh, good point, thanks. I've edited that in. Interestingly, it doesn't sound natural to "give a surprise" without the indirect object.

Answer (score 1):

- I organized a surprise party for my friend.
- I had or held a surprise party for my friend.
- I gave my friend a surprise by having a party for him.
- I surprised my friend with a party.

So, here, neither make or do is right.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that only one of these three examples use "surprise" as a noun: the first two use it as an adjective qualifying "party", and the last uses it as a verb. That leaves "I gave my friend a surprise" which I already mentioned in my answer (thanks to Kate Bunting's suggestion).

Comment: @IMSoP Frankly, thee grammar  is the least of it. The fact we say neither make or do is the main point.

Comment: True. I just thought the OP might not spot the distinction, and think that *"I held a surprise for my friend" would be acceptable, when it is not. I was also curious if you thought there was something missing in my answer, which was posted some time before this one.